# Eclipse is not starting

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, java-6

My eclipse is not working and this error occurs every time. I have windows 7 (32 bit). MY JRE JDK and eclipse folders are in the same location.

```
A java environment(JRE) or JDK must be available on order to run eclipse. 
No java virtual machine was found after searching the following location 
C:\Program Files\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe javew.exe un your current path.
```

Comment: could u plz add the file content of "eclipse.ini" in ur question?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check that path? Do you have a custom installation of JDK? Do you have JDK at all? We need more info to answer your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your local JDK runtime to the PATH system variable: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html